# Is a pooled db-access using method-level connection in a static class/method safe?

Tags: java, connection-pooling, static-methods

have been a long-time reader here and now I`ve got a problem I can´t really get my head around.

For ease of access and to save object creation overhead I have a static class realizing database accesses. The used JVM implementation is Tomcat and for connection pooling org.apache.commons.dbcp is used.

I've read a lot about thread-safety, heap and stack here and elsewhere but I can`t get to a definitive conclusion if multiple method calls on my static class won't interfere with each other. Most topics I've read deal with instance methods while I use static ones which might have implications I overlooked.

If I understood everything correctly, as the variables connection, statement, resultset are on the method level, each function call should have a unique reference on the stack to a unique object in the heap and it should not be possible that multiple method calls interfere with each other.

Am I right or do I stand corrected? Any help would be appreciated.

The (shortened) code is :

```
public class DBQuery{


private static String pathToDataSource = "";
private static javax.naming.Context cxt = null;
private static javax.sql.DataSource ds = null;


private static void getDataSource() throws Exception {
  if(pathToDataSource.equals("")){ pathToDataSource = Config.getParam("PathToDataSource"); }
  cxt = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
  ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) cxt.lookup(pathToDataSource);
}


private static Connection connect() throws Exception {
  if(ds==null){ getDataSource(); }
  return ds.getConnection();
}


public static Vector doDBquery(String querystring) throws Exception {
  Vector retVec = new Vector();
  Connection connection = null;
  Statement statement = null;
  ResultSet resultset = null;
  try {
    connection = getConnection();
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    resultset = statement.executeQuery(querystring);    
    ...
  } catch(Exception e) {
    ...
  } finally {
    myFinallyBlock(resultset, statement, connection);
  }
  return retVec;
}


// more methods like doDBInsert() following, hence closure in separate myFinallyBlock


private static void myFinallyBlock(ResultSet resultset, Statement statement, Connection connection) {
  try {
    if (resultset != null) resultset.close();
  } catch (SQLException e) { resultset = null; }
  try {
    if (statement != null) statement.close();
  } catch (SQLException e) { statement = null; }
  try {
    if (connection != null) connection.close();
  } catch (SQLException e) { connection = null; }
}


} //close class
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you are right inside method there is no concurrency problems , until you are using shared variables inside it, in other words **"Stateless objects are always thread-safe."**

Servlet is quite good example of it ;)

**edited.**

For making your code safe I recommend you to do follow:

```
private static Connection connect() throws Exception {
  if (ds == null) {
    synchronized (Connection.class) {
      if (ds == null) {
        getDataSource();
      }
    }
  }
  return ds.getConnection();
}
```

Comment: That would be wonderful news, but does a static class count as a stateless object? It seems to me it's very much the same but there really is no instanced object. That's exactly my problem because other topics are always about instantiatable classes.

Comment: Thanks for Your suggestion, if I read this right, the DataSource initialization can then be executed by only one Thread without concurrent access by others, while using Connection.class as monitor allows other Threads to call other methods meanwhile, correct ?

Comment: Nope,it will lock whole class during connection initialization, but your class not so much useful without connection plus it is not so big time , and after initialization it will work without any performance impact. But if you are bothering about performance for initialization you can make your connection as static final and set up it in static initialization block.

Comment: Im not worried at all but thankful. Just thinking about Your code has taught me a lot; You double the null check cause in the meantime it might have already been initialized and You don`t synchronize getDataSource() as a whole because at first it could just get reinitialized some times.I first had a static global Connection that led to "Connection already closed" errors, naturally since all calls worked on the same Connection object. Hence this method level approach.

Comment: So I just tried to understand Your approach and thought attaching the monitor to sth. other than DBquery.class would not lock the whole class. Why attach it to Connection.class, then? Of course you`re right about it not being useful while without DataSource. Thanks so much for Your help and insight :-)

Comment: Thank you, I think this will clarify it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking ;)